# How to establish communication frontend(Reactjs) to SQL Server database?

Tags: reactjs, sql-server, database, rest

I have a React app and want to get data from SQL Server database.

I did some research and found that we can do it using Hasura and Docker: https://hasura.io/docs/latest/databases/ms-sql-server/getting-started/docker/

But I do not want to use Hasura or Docker and I'm trying to write my own server/api to do this. Any idea how this can be done and which programming language must be used? Can I use Node.js?

Comment: Definitely can use Node.js. Checkout Node.js libraries mssql, tedious, node-sqlserver sure there are some others. You can use Node.js Express library to expose your REST endpoints that can be accessed by your React App.

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. You can use whatever language you want for implementing an API, so long as it can talk to SQL Server on the backend and de/serialize something that your clients can consume (XML, JSON, etc.) on the frontend. Probably the main considerations are what languages are you familiar with and where do you want to host it (in the cloud, or self-managed).